# How to reuse phone board without casing, screen

Tags: adb, root-access

I have galaxy j7 2016 board with [this rom](https://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-j7/samsung-galaxy-j7-2016-exynos-7870-guides-development-and-mods/sm-j710fn-deluxeromux-t3626362) installed. I have a lot of knowledge about hardware but my question is how to access shell without screen if usb debugging is not enabled? I basically want to control system via adb. I have board, both cameras, both speakers and vibration motor. Im planning to add antennas.

Board rev: SM-J710F_REV03 2016.03.15 V10

Can someone explain me how to take control over phone without screen and digitizer?

Comment: Can you access another Galaxy J7 2016?

Comment: I tough about that but i cant. That's why I asked this question.